# C# service reference and SOAP header

Tags: c#, soap

In my program I have a reference to a webservice. This webservice however, requires authentication:

```
        <headers>
          <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken>
              <Username>{username}</Username>
              <Password>{password}</Password>
            </UsernameToken>
          </Security>
        </headers>
```

How can I add this kind of authentication in my program, requesting the webservice?

Something like the below does not seem to work:

```
      client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
      client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

I would like to avoid putting something in my app.config:

```
<headers>
                  <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                      <UsernameToken>
                          <Username>{username}</Username>
                          <Password>{password}</Password>
                      </UsernameToken>
                  </Security>
              </headers>
```

This is working, but not the way I would like it to have.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
 public async Task<string> HttpClientAsync(string url , string json, string token)
            {
                try
                {
                    var JsonData = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
                    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
                    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                        (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
                        {
                            return true;
                        };
                    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                    {
                        //  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", token);
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "");
                        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, JsonData);
                        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        return resultContent;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return e.Message;
                }
    
            }
```

Comment: This solution bypass the referenced webservice right?
How to set the token for this?